# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно переносить?

Tags: перенос

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переносятся слова «демонической» и
«повседневную» с пояснениями.

Answer (score 0):

Переносим мы по слогам

1. Де-мо-ни-чес-кой. Ничего тут нельзя переместить, т.к. нельзя переносить не по слогам.
2. Пов-сед-нев-ную. "Пов" - потому что от приставки согласную(если за ней следует еще согласная) отделять нельзя. "Ю" на конце нельзя отделить, одну букву переносить(или оставлять) нельзя на строке.

Comment: Пожалуйста, сообщите то, что я не объяснил. Я постараюсь доработать

Comment: Может, так лучше? По — все — днев — ную.  Согласную нельзя отделять от корня.